# integer not saving within a loop/partially working JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, loops, readline

I am new at javascript and currently writing a basic file that is run in terminal. The majority of it is working. It allows the user to add credit/remove credit and check their credit. The last part is allowing them to buy a product and have that amount be removed from their overall credit.

The issue I have is, while it does show the amount has been removed when purchasing an item. When going back to the menu and checking the remaining credit afterwards it is back to it's original amount.

I have tried using the code below instead to save the credit (which it does even after checking the credit available):

```
    credit -= readlineSync.keyInSelect(products, 'What product would you like?');
```

But because the array uses a number the user inputs, it is removing that number from the overall credit instead of the actual price. So for example, if the user selects option 4, it removes 4 from the credit when in fact the Candy is £3.

Any help that can be given would be greatly appreciated, as i have spent quite a long time without finding a solution.

Comment: Just a friendly reminder, it is usually customary to mark an answer as correct if it solved your problem, as it helps both your reputation and ours when you do so.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you never update the credit after they purchase a product
all that following line does is how much they would have it you done it right :)

```
console.log('Thank you, your Candy has now been dispensed. Your total credit is now £' + (credit - removeCredit - 3));
```

the solution is quite simple, update credit and then show them, for example:

```
if (index == 3) {
    credit = credit - 4;
    console.log('Thank you, your Candy has now been dispensed. Your total credit is now £' + credit);
}
```

so your code should look like

```
 var readlineSync = require('readline-sync');
 var credit = 0;
 var removeCredit = 0;

 menu = [];
 menu[0] = "Purchase a product";
 menu[1] = "View your credit";
 menu[2] = "Add credit";
 menu[3] = "Retrieve a refund";
 menu[4] = "Quit!";

 products = [];
 products[0] = "Drink: £1";
 products[1] = "Crisps: £1";
 products[2] = "Chocolate: £2";
 products[3] = "Candy: £3";

 do {
     index = readlineSync.keyInSelect(menu, 'Please choose your option');
     if (index == 1) {
         console.log("The total amount of credit you have is: £", credit);
     }

     if (index == 2) {
         credit += readlineSync.questionInt('How much credit would you to purchase? ');
         console.log("The total amount of credit you have is: £" + credit);
     }

     if (index == 3) {
         credit -= readlineSync.questionInt('How much credit would you like to remove? ');
         console.log("This credit has now been removed, your total available credit is: £" + credit);
     }
     if (index == 0) {
         index = readlineSync.keyInSelect(products, 'What product would you like?');
         if (index == 0) {
            credit = credit - 1;
            console.log('Thank you, your Drink has now been dispensed. Your total credit is now £' + credit);
         }
         if (index == 1) {
            credit = credit - 1;
            console.log('Thank you, your Crisps have now been dispensed. Your total credit is now £' + credit);
         }
         if (index == 2) {
            credit = credit - 2;
            console.log('Thank you, your Chocolate has now been dispensed. Your total credit is now £' + credit);
         }
         if (index == 3) {
            credit = credit - 3;
            console.log('Thank you, your Candy has now been dispensed. Your total credit is now £' + credit);
         }
     }
 } while (index != 4)
```

Comment: Ahh thanks for clarifying where i went wrong! It's now working correctly. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

I cleaned up your code a bit and fixed what you observed as the problem:

```
var readlineSync = require('readline-sync');
var credit = 0;
var index;

var menu = [
    'Purchase a product',
    'View your credit',
    'Add credit',
    'Retrieve a refund',
    'Quit!'
];

var products = [
    'Drink',
    'Crisps',
    'Chocolate',
    'Candy'
];

var prices = [1, 1, 2, 3];

var productList = products.map(function(product, i) {
    return product + ': £' + prices[i];
});

do {
    index = readlineSync.keyInSelect(menu, 'Please choose your option');

    if (index == 1) {
        console.log('The total amount of credit you have is: £%d', credit);
    }

    if (index == 2) {
        credit += readlineSync.questionInt('How much credit would you to purchase? ');
        console.log('The total amount of credit you have is: £%d', credit);
    }

    if (index == 3) {
        credit -= readlineSync.questionInt('How much credit would you like to remove? ');
        console.log('This credit has now been removed, your total available credit is: £%d', credit);
    }

    if (index == 0) {
        index = readlineSync.keyInSelect(productList, 'What product would you like?');

        if (index >= 0 && index < products.length) {
            credit -= prices[index];
            console.log('Thank you, your %s has now been dispensed. Your total credit is now £%d', products[index], credit);
        }

        continue;
    }

} while(index != 4);
```

A couple of key things here, and I'll address some of the issues I saw which you didn't point out:

1. You never declared `index`. While this is considered valid in non-strict mode, this is bad practice since assigning an undeclared variable exposes it to the global scope.
2. You didn't have an array of `prices`, so of course you were going to run into problems figuring out what value to subtract from your credit. I took the liberty of adding that array for you.
3. Splitting the products list from the prices list had the benefit of reducing the [WETness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself) of your code, and then I reconstructed the original list using an [array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function.

Here's the breakdown of that:

```
var productList = products.map(function(product, i) {
    return product + ': £' + prices[i];
});
```

This function iterates through the values in `products` and for each value `product` and each index `i`, it returns a new string in the format of `product: £price`, storing that to the respective index of array `productList`.

4. I changed your `console.log` statements to use inline formatting to make it cleaner. `%s` means put a string here, and `%d` means put an integer here. The following arguments are then used to fill in those format specifiers.
5. I added a `continue` statement inside your last `if` block to return to the loop early. This is because `index` is overwritten by your selection of the product, so it no longer reflects the original menu selection.

Feel free to post comments if you have any questions about my feedback.

Comment: Thanks you for taking the time to clean up the code and most importantly explain what these changes have done. It's helped to clarify my understanding a lot more, so for that I thank you!